# Angularjs How to clear angularjs-bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

On the click of reset button I'm trying to clear all my form fields but I'm unable to clear angular-bootstrap-datepicker.This is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Strting, Ending Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 45%;float: left;">
            <input class="fa fa-calendar" id="dpStartDate" name="startdate" type="text" data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" ng-model="job.StartDate">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 45%;float: right;">
            <input class="form-control" id="dpEndDate" name="enddate" type="text" data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" ng-model="job.EndDate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn" ng-click="clearFields()" style="margin-left: 8px">Reset</button>

$scope.datepickerOptions = {
                            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                            language: 'en',
                            autoclose: true,
                            weekStart: 0
                        }
```

I have made number of unsuccessful attempts like

```
$scope.job = {},(all fields other than two datepickers become blank)
$scope.job.StartDate = ''
$scope.job.StartDate = null
```

Comment: Setting the $scope.job.StartDate = null should work. Can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: Any resolution found for this one ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a issue with the specific version of the `ui-bootstrap` library. Have a look [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1957). You can replace the library with the latest one to get rid of the issue. However you have any apprehensions regarding other code and do not intent to replace the library, you can try the following hack.

Provide an identifier to your `<input>` element of the datepicker and then set the model to `null` as below

`angular.element("#strtDate")[0].value = null;`

This worked for me. Hope it helps you too.